# How can I move signin modal form the right hand (top) of my website

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, layout, frontend

I have the following problem and to be honest dont know what I am doing wrong.

Recenty I have added a Bootstrap    *Sign In*  modal into my html.

```
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm">SIGN IN</a>
</div>
```

and

```
                                              <!-- Sign In Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Sign up</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body mx-3">
        <div class="md-form mb-5">
          <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
          <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" class="form-control validate">
          <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Your name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="md-form mb-5">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
          <input type="email" id="orangeForm-email" class="form-control validate">
          <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Your email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="md-form mb-4">
          <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
          <input type="password" id="orangeForm-pass" class="form-control validate">
          <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-pass">Your password</label>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-deep-orange" onclick="bypassSignUp()"> >Sign up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I have added it, I put it at the buttom of my html (It was suppose to be part of the *navn bar*)

And this is how it looks in the html

[image]
When I click on it  I see the *Sign Up* form, as expected:

[image]

This is the whole *html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Nome</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
      <script>
         function bypassSignUp() {
             // For testing purposes, you can directly redirect to the user page after bypassing sign-up
             alert('Bypassing sign-up. Redirecting to user page...');
             window.location.href = 'user_page.html';
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="nav-bar">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400"></a>
               <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                  aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">HOME</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">SERVICES</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">ABOUT US</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">TESTIMONIALS</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">CONTACT</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">
                           <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                              data-bs-target="#loginModal">LOGIN</div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
      </section>
      <section id="banner">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6"></div>
               <p class="promo-title">Esercizio Luglio 2023</p>
               <p>Check the tutorials</p>
               <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="play-btn">Watch Tutorials</a>
               <div class="col-md-6 text-center ms-auto">
                  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="image-fluid">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Login Modal incomplete -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
      </div>
      <!-- Sign In Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header text-center">
                  <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Sign up</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                     <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Your name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                     <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="email" id="orangeForm-email" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Your email</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                     <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="password" id="orangeForm-pass" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-pass">Your password</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <button class="btn btn-deep-orange" onclick="bypassSignUp()"> >Sign up</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
         <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm">SIGN IN</a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have "moved" the *SIGN IN* button at the top, but when I click on it, it doesn't work.
The *SIGN IN* form doesn't pop up.

[image]

This is the *html* I have modified:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Nome</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
      <script>
         function bypassSignUp() {
             // For testing purposes, you can directly redirect to the user page after bypassing sign-up
             alert('Bypassing sign-up. Redirecting to user page...');
             window.location.href = 'user_page.html';
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="nav-bar">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #EFEFEF;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400"></a>
               <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                  aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
               </button>
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">HOME</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">SERVICES</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">ABOUT US</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">TESTIMONIALS</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #EFEFEF;">CONTACT</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: #FFD166;">
                           <div class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                              data-bs-target="#loginModal">LOGIN</div>
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                     <li class="nav-link">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm"> SIGN IN
                        </a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </nav>
      </section>
      <section id="banner">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6"></div>
               <p class="promo-title">Esercizio Luglio 2023</p>
               <p>Check the tutorials</p>
               <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="play-btn">Watch Tutorials</a>
               <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="image-fluid">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" class="bottom-img">
      </section>
      <!-- Login Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <!-- Add your login modal content here -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header text-center">
                  <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Sign up</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                     <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Your name</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-5">
                     <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="email" id="orangeForm-email" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-email">Your email</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                     <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                     <input type="password" id="orangeForm-pass" class="form-control validate">
                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-pass">Your password</label>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <button class="btn btn-deep-orange" onclick="bypassSignUp()"> >Sign up</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be due to renaming the `data-toggle` attribute to `data-bs-toggle` in your latest HTML file. Rename the attribute back.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I didnt put attention on to that detail, many thanks again.